# Mudar strings de um objeto em um foreach

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach

Estou com problema: eu monto um objeto a partir de um lista de inserção:

[image: 1° imagem - objeto montado dinamicamente]

Essa lista eu coloco em uma variável e insiro dentro de uma função com foreach, porém, para que funcione corretamente dentro da função não pode ter aspas (") nos registros;
O correto é para ficar da seguinte forma:

[image: 2° imagem - como deve ficar, vindo da variável dinâmica]

Dessa forma, com as aspas em cada registro, o resultado final não tem os dados do Array que é feita a função do foreach e sim como está escrito na primeira imagem, é impresso como: [`"Bairro: row.bairro"`] por causa das aspas. Eu preciso fazer com que fique como na segunda imagem.

Retorno da variável associated:

[image: array - associated]

Função sem ser dinâmica:

[image: função completa]

Função que monto o objeto:

[image: função que monto o objeto]

Lista para escolha dinâmica dos itens:

[image: lista para escolha dos itens]

Comment: os caras colocam negativo e nem entenderam a função, negativa a gente sem saber, ao invés de ajudar, só pode ser iniciante...

Comment: Você poderia dar um exemplo como está sua variável "this.associated"?

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: @BrunoCunha, a questão não é nem o retorno desse array, pq se eu fizer manualmente como na 2° imagem, eu consigo imprimir corretamente, a questão é o objeto que é montado (dinamicamente) para escolher os itens a serem impressos. Então no final eu tenho um objeto com os itens escolhidos. Porém, quando tenho juntar a função do foreach, a aspa atrapalha a função não imprime o valor correto, o certo seria tirar as aspas e ficar como na 2° imagem

Comment: @HenriqueMendesSilveiraRodri, como está a sua função forEach que está criando o objeto com as aspas, ela sumiu da pergunta?

Comment: @BrunoCunha, eu não crio o objeto com a função foreach, o objeto é uma parte da função foreach. é um objeto normal que eu crio através de uma lista de opções, vou icrementando conforme o usuário vai selecionando e no fim eu monto um objeto, como na 1°  imagem

Comment: @BrunoCunha, coloquei a função completa que gera o excel, porém ela não está dinâmica. Eu quero deixar dinâmica no objeto que compõe a linha 155 à 175. É como se isso estive hardcode, e quero deixar dinâmica, passando um objeto com o mesmo padrão, porém preciso montar esse objeto sem as aspas embrulhando cada registro

Comment: Certo, to começando a entender, poderia só colocar tbm como está sua função dinâmica?

Comment: @BrunoCunha, coloquei a função que monto o objeto, deixando a dinâmica, bem como a lista também que é mostrada. Dessa lista, eu só aproveito a última parte [row] como pode ver na função que monto o objeto com spread operator na linha 107

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: @Bacco, obrigado pela sugestão, mas editei mais de três x conversando com o Bruno, para ter um entendimento melhor, o que pretendo fazer é realmente complicado, mas se ler toda a questão acredito que esteja compreensível meu problema, no final se trata apenas de como tirar as aspas dos registros do objeto da 1° imagem

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você deseja montar um objeto dinâmico com os atributos que estão marcado com `checked: true` no seu itemsList.

O seu resultado final está ficando "Bairro: row.bairro", pois você está incluindo no seu array apenas strings.

Uma solução que encontrei seria filtrar apenas os itens que estão com `checked: true`, e depois iterar sobre o seu array `associated` criando novos objetos apenas com os atributos que vc deseja.

```js
const itemsList = [
 {"id": 1, "name": "bairro", "checked": true, "row": "bairro", "title": "Bairro"},
 {"id": 2, "name": "celular", "checked": false, "row": "celular", "title": "Celular"},
 {"id": 3, "name": "cep", "checked": true, "row": "cep", "title": "Cep"},
];

const associated = [
  {"bairro": 'PARAISO', 'celular': "11111", 'cep': '29144-254'},
  {"bairro": 'OSASCO', 'celular': "22222", 'cep': '22455-774'},
];

// filtro apenas os itemsList que estão como true
const listRowsIterable = itemsList.filter(item => item.checked == true);

//monto objeto dinamicamente apenas com os atributos que quero 
const excel = associated.map(row => {
  let rowExcel = {};
  listRowsIterable.forEach(item => {
    //item.title - adiciona um atributo dinâmico no seu novo objeto
    //item.row - pega o valor que está no seu objeto associated dinâmicamente 
    rowExcel[item.title] = row[item.row];
  });
  return rowExcel;
});

console.log(excel);
```